# Attachments don't delete after sending email when looping

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is used to send out an email with an attachment and does that fine. The problem I have is:

1. that the code is called again to perform the same function, but the attachments don't delete after sending, hence, it will keep adding the new attachment to an existing batch of those already sent. I've tried to add ".Attachments.Remove" just before the add attachment, but keep getting an error on this line.
2. The second thing I would really appreciate assistance with, is to tell the code when to 'stop' if lets say, the next email has previously been sent, hence, move on the next email, etc., and when to stop if all emails have already been sent.

---

```
Sub email_PO()


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
File_name = Sheet2.Cells(3, 10)
attach_name = Sheet2.Cells(28, 10)
attach_file = Sheet2.Cells(60, 10)
pasteAt = Sheet2.Cells(62, 10)

Windows(File_name).Activate
Sheets("Control").Select
Bodytosend = Sheet2.Range("A581:E596")

mail_to_ATTA = Sheet2.Cells(58, 10)
mail_cc_ATTA = Sheet2.Cells(59, 10)
Subject = Sheet2.Cells(57, 10)

Sheets("Control").Select
Range("A39").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ANCHOr:=Selection, Address:= _
attach_link, TextToDisplay:= _
""

Dim Sendrng As Range
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With
Sheets("Control").Select
Range("A581:H604").Select
Set Sendrng = Selection
With Sendrng
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With .Parent.MailEnvelope
.Introduction = ""

With .Item


.To = mail_to_ATTA
.Cc = mail_cc_ATTA
.Subject = Subject
.Attachments.Remove
.Attachments.Add (attach_file)
.VotingOptions = "Purchased Order Acknowledged & Agree to T&C's;Purchase Order Declined"
.SEND
End With
End With

End With

StopMacro:
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False


Windows(File_name).Activate

Sheets("Control").Select
Range("J61").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PO Tracker").Select
Range(pasteAt).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


Range("A1").Select

Call email_PO


Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Attachments.Remove 1` May work
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868839.aspx) says that "The 1-based index value of the object within the collection." or in laymans speach you need to tell it which attachment to remove

Not sure if you are using outlook but in your VBA you can try going to "Tools" > "References" and add Microsoft Outlook SharePoint social Provider, Social Provider Extensibility and View Control

If you need further clarification of anything just leave a comment and i'll get back to you when I can

Comment: Mr. Burns, thank you very much indeed for your kind assistance herewith. I've followed your instructions above which has sorted my problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Ramon Scorgie , Great to hear that this helped, there is a tick,just below the up and down arrorw on the left side of the answer, to accept the answer as an answer

Comment: This site has really benefited over the past two weeks while completing a project. Thanks to everyone who so willingly contribute to it.

Comment: GLad to hear that SO has beena ble to help, hope we see you more!